# PHP Anonymous Function doesn't want to execute

Tags: php

I'm recreating parts of Laravel in plain PHP for a school project and I've been trying to make the following code work. I've been trying to get an output, but I don't seem to get it right. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Route {
    public static function get($path) {
        return $path;
    }
}

function view($val)  {
    require_once $val . '.php';
}

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('console');
});
```

The following code should include console.php, but it does nothing.

Comment: Can you confirm that your anonymous function is being called? What do you mean by "it does nothing"? If you swap out `return view('console');` with `error_log('console');` (or `echo 'test'; die();`, etc.) does that work? Prove that "nothing" is happening, and then debug from there. :) Edit: `get()` only takes one parameter. Per its logic, it should be returning `'/'`. How are you expecting your anonymous function to execute?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Right, so if I replace every return/require_once with print_r() with values 1, 2, 3 it only returns 1. Meaning that only the get function will be executed.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones If I accept another argument in get(), it only returns an empty Closure Object.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Oh you're right! I completely forgot about that. I indeed needed to add a second argument and execute it within get. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `get()` parameters to accept a second parameter, and then call that function - I believe you can do this like `$function()`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php for more examples.

```
class Route {
    public static function get($path, $function) {
        $function();
        return $path;
    }
}

function view($val)  {
    require_once $val . '.php';
}

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('console');
});
```